# Custom component default style (Failed to find style in current theme)

Tags: android

I wanna extend the existing android widgets with custom one, however I'm already stuck at the very beginning, I get the following error: "Failed to find style 'autoCompleteTextViewStyle' in current theme".

My goal is to create custom components for specific data like email here, or phone number or credit card number that I use all over my app, then I can write validation code once and apply it in the component class, so I dont have to attach validators for every field like I would have to do with standard EditText fields. But apart from that they'd look like the standard widgets.

Here is what I did:

```
public class EmailView extends AutoCompleteTextView {
    public EmailView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public EmailView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public EmailView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
}
```

And trying to use it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <lu.intech.wega.ui.component.EmailView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I read on some forums that I should declare styles in styles.xml. But I dont wanna have to declare a style for every custom composant I create, I just want them to look exactly like their parent components, I will just add custom treatment on them but they'll look the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that my Gradle version wasn't up to date (somehow the config wasn't commited when I pushed from my other computer), so I just changed the corresponding line in build.gradle (Project: myProjet) and rebuilt the project and it worked!